# Sending params with POST Req in JSON with AFNetworking

Tags: objective-c, json, post, afnetworking

I have a small problem with `AFNetworking`.

I'm not able to send the parameters and the data to my server (php-Skript)

The data (from `NSDictionary`) have to be JSON.

Ignore the senseless code parts please.

I'm receiving Errors like:

> NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/html}
>   or Error: Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1016 "Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/html"

```
NSDictionary *parameter = [[NSDictionary alloc]init];

parameter = @{@"device-id": @"iOSDeveloper1234567432",@"system": @1,@"token": @"iOS-TestToken",@"mail_enabled": @"false",@"mail": @"NULL", @"movies": @[@"matrix", @"matrix2", @"matrix3"]};

NSError *error;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:parameter options:0 error:nil];

NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:URL];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                   timeoutInterval:60.0];

[request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *stringkey;
stringkey = (@"k=");
stringkey = [stringkey stringByAppendingString:APIKEY];
NSString *strings;
NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
myString = [myString stringByAppendingString:(@"&k=")];
    myString = [myString stringByAppendingString:APIKEY];

NSLog(@"%@",myString);


myString = [myString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

request.HTTPBody = [myString dataUsingEncoding:NSSymbolStringEncoding];


NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:parameter options:0 error:&error];
NSLog(@"%@",error.localizedDescription);

AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
[manager GET:URL parameters:myString progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

Comment: Maya by adding setting `AFResponseJSONSerializer` to the `AFHTTPSessionManager`?

Comment: is this available in AFNetworking 3?

Comment: You server seems to send "text/html" as content type instead of application/json